# How to debug my c# application in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have a small c# application which creates some folders and I want to debug it.I have added an Debugger.Break() inside my code & but I am not able to attach the process to the visual studio because as soon an I click on the exe to start it finishes its operation.Surely I am missing something silly here.Any solutions?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` at the end? If it's a console application it should work

Comment: You can also put `Debugger.Launch();` instead of `Break`, which will give you the opportunity to attach first.

Comment: Also, I hope you realise you're able to run the program *from* visual studio with the F5 key? If you want to pass command line arguments, you can do that in the project properties' Debug page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a breakpoint in your code.  Click on the gray gutter running down the left hand side of your code editor window, where there is a line of code.  A red dot should appear and that is your breakpoint.  You may need to try a few different lines as you cannot break on all lines of code.  Now run your app from within Visual Studio by clicking on the green arrow (continue) button in the toolbar.  When the execution hits that breakpoint, it should stop and you will be able to debug from there from within Visual Studio.

I suggest you read this for more info [Getting started with Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986851.aspx)